# how can resolve sysic syntax error in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm new in `matlab`, I want to use `sysic` but got error on `outputvar`.

this my code:

```
clc;
clear;
clear all;

s1 = zpk('s');
himat = 3*((s1+1)*(s1+5))/((s1+2)*(s1+10)); display('himat = ');
display(himat);

k = s1;
systemnames = ' himat k ';
inputvar = '[ pertin;dis]';
outputvar = '[ wdel; wp]';
input_to_himat = '[ k + pertin ]';
input_to_k = '[ -dist - himat ]';
sysoutname = 'clp';
cleanupsysic = 'yes';
sysic;
```

any help to resolve this issue?

Comment: may be `inputvar = '[ pertin{2};dis{2}]';` helps

Comment: i got syntax error on `outputvar`,i tried `inputvar = '[ pertin{2};dis{2}]'; `but i got same error again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error was happen because `k+pertin` and `-dist-himat` was not define in `outputvar`!! :)